# Detect AND, OR in the sentence and split it

Tags: javascript

I have the following user queries:

```
Boeing AND Airbus OR twitter
Boeing AND Airbus
```

I need to split words in them by AND, OR so, in the end, I will have something like this:

```
"Boeing" AND "Airbus"
"Boeing" AND "Airbus" OR "twitter"
```

How can I do this with split or any other method?

Comment: whats the difference of expected result to current value?

Comment: `.split(/AND|OR/g)` ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes that splited words will be in ""

Comment: [].concat.apply([], "Boeing AND Airbus OR twitter".split("AND").map(e => e.split("OR")))

Comment: @JonasWilms split works well but now I need somehow made them as one string with "Boeing" AND "Airbus" OR "twitter"

Comment: @JonasWilms why it is unclear what I asked???? I wrote what I have and the expected result! Why Unamata Sanatarai understood and adviced me exactly what I need and you put my question on hold!

Comment: (1) Don't take it personal. We closed the question, not *your question*. (2) We closed it. Three people did, not just me. (3) you are asking about "splitting the words", yet your wanted result seems to be one string. thats a source for missunderstanding. (4) This site requires you to [*show what you have tried towards a solution*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), you haven't shown much yet.

Comment: I didn't write what I tried because I don't have anything. Would it be better if I write sentence.split(' ') ???? I wrote my problem and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step:

1. split on space
2. Iterate through elements, if is NOT "and" or "OR" -> quote

```js
const sentence = "Boeing AND Airbus OR twitter"

const split = sentence.split(" ");

const quoted = split.map(e => ["AND", "OR"].includes(e)?e:'"'+e+'"')

console.log(quoted.join(" "))
```